# Calculate a 2-way set?

Tags: combinatorics

I am having difficulty intersecting two different sets. The first set is formatted structured set while the second set is unstructured. That is values can interchange positions with each other in second set. I will explain with an example:

First Set:
$$[(1..5, 1..12)]$$

Second Set:
$$[(A..Z, 0..9, 0..9)]$$

The second set can have 3 sets such as:
$$[(A..Z, 0..9, 0..9)], [(0..9, A..Z, 0..9)], [(0..9, 0..9, A..Z)]$$

So an intersection example of First set and Second set would be a total of 5 placement of values

Examples:
$$[(1, 5), (A, 2, 9)],$$
$$[(3, 11), (8, T, 9)],$$
$$[(4, 12), (9, 2, P)],$$
$$[(1, 2), (A, 1, 0)],$$
$$[(5, 10), (F, 2, 9)],$$
$$[(5, 7), (3, A, 3)],$$

So my question is how many number of sets can be generated with intersection of structured 1st set and unstructured 2nd set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the intersection the first item is from structured 1st set. 
There is 5*12=60 (we choose from 5 numbers to create the first item in tuple and from 12 to create the second) possibilities how to generate it.

The second item is from unstructured 2st set. There would be 26*10*10=2 600 possibilities if the set was, as in the first case, structured. Because it is not, we have to multiply it by 3 as the items can be shuffled. The number of possibilities is then 2 600*3=7 800.

The number of sets that can be generated with intersection of structured 1st set and unstructured 2nd set is 
60*7 800 = 468 000.